# Mysql Operation timeout Error

Tags: php, mysql, macos, sockets, xampp

> Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Operation timed out in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/conn.php on line 4
>       Connection failed: Operation timed out

Get the following **error** while connecting to **XAMPP** on **Mac OS** X.
Code line is

```
    $conn=mysqli_connect("SNA","root","","localhost");

            // Check connection
            if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
              echo "Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
            }
```

Is it a Mysql Host problem or a Mysql default socket problem and how to resolve it? Default Host is 3306. I dont know where my mysql.sock file is generated and whether its generating or not.

Comment: Is `SNA` your DB name? Try `$conn=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "SNA");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change your code here, interchange host and database name

```
 $conn=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","SNA");
```

check php manual for more info : http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php